# How to improve drag&drop for mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm trying to implement a drag$drop effect similar to Tinder app using javascript.

The monipulation works fine on chrome mobile emulator via chrome debugger tool, but when i try to run it on a real mobile device (nexus 5, chrome mobile) it lags very hard.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
  $(function() {

    $('body').on('touchstart', function(){
        $('.item').bind('touchmove',function(e){

            var self = this;
            var xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
            $(self).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                'transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                'left' : xPos+'px'


            });
//            debugger
        })
    })
});
```

CSS

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.data {

    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}


div.item {

    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
    background: goldenrod;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    line-height:70px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

}
```

HTML
    ...

```
</head>
<body>


        <div class="item">
          Item
        </div>

<div class="data"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the selectors for 'body' and '.item'. So there wont be any traveling on DOM later.

```
 var bodyness=$('body');
 var itemness=$('.item');

    $(function() {

    bodyness.on('touchstart', function(){
        itemness.bind('touchmove',function(e){

            var self = this;
            var xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
            $(self).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                'transform' : 'rotate('+ xPos +'deg)',
                'left' : xPos+'px'


            });
//            debugger
        })
    })
});
```